Next Bitcoin Core client version
I'm currently using the 27.1.0 Bitcoin Core client version and I have a question about the next version.
Will it be the 27.2.0 or the 28.0.0 version ?
Update : The v28 will be available soon I guess, I saw one recently ! 

The version numbering scheme is explained at https://bitcoincore.org/en/lifecycle/#versioning

Versioning
Bitcoin Core releases are versioned as follows:
MAJOR.MINOR, and release candidates are suffixed with rc1, rc2 etc.
Major releases
We aim to make a major release every 6-7 months.
These will be numbered 22.0, 23.0 etc.
Maintenance releases
We will provide maintenance “minor releases” that
fix bugs within the major releases. As a general rule we do not
introduce major new features in a maintenance release (except for
consensus rules). However, we may add minor features where necessary,
and we will back-port consensus rule changes such as soft forks.
Minor releases will be numbered 22.1, 22.2, 23.1, 23.2 etc.

So it depends what bugs are found, if any, that need to be fixed within the major version release cycle.

Bitcoin Core version numbers are of the form MAJOR.MINOR. The major number goes up when features are added, the minor number goes up when bugs are fixed.
The latest version as of 2024-Aug-16 is 27.1, which is part of the major series 27.x. The next major version will be 28.0, and is scheduled to be released on 2024-Sep-30. It will start the 28.x series.
If bugs are found that are worth fixing in 27.1, there will be a 27.2. This can happen before or after 28.0 comes out. If so, it will have only the 27.x features and not the 28.x ones.
